# How to disable smooth animation by setting the same speed in .animate method

Tags: jquery

I use the **.animate** method, and I had a question about setting the speed of movement. The example shows that the speed of movement changes (at the beginning and at the end it is slower), how to set the same speed?

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
   $('.overflow').animate( { scrollLeft: "500" },10000);   
});
```

```css
 
 
.overflow {
         overflow-x:scroll;
         width:300px;
         white-space: nowrap;
 }
.a {
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     margin:0 20px;
     display:inline-block;
     background:red;
  }
#button{
    background:#ccc;
    padding:10px;
    border:0.5px solid #eee;
    width:100px;text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="overflow">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>

<div id="button">Start</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the keyword `"linear"` as the third argument of

```
$('.overflow').animate( { scrollLeft: "500" },10000);
```

to get the constant speed for the movement.

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
   $('.overflow').animate( { scrollLeft: "500" },10000, "linear");   
});
```

```css
.overflow {overflow-x:scroll;width:300px;
    white-space: nowrap;}
.a {width:100px;height:100px;margin:0 20px;display:inline-block;background:red;}
#button{background:#ccc;padding:10px;border:0.5px solid #eee;width:100px;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="overflow">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>

<div id="button">Start</div>
```